# CSS: Striped diamond

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I can do a diamond, and I can do stripes with CSS. I'm having issues merging the two to get a striped diamond. Please see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3PNs/) (works on Chrome).

How can I make a striped diamond?

```
#diamond {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 80px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px
}
#diamond:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 80px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid red;
}

.stripes {
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  background-size: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
}
```

Comment: Until border gradients are supported this particular technique will not work.

Comment: I was working on your last question when you deleted it. This needs some work, but it's a start: http://jsbin.com/alinup/2/edit

Comment: @TomSmilack: You're empty diamond is fantastic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually do it with just 1 element and less CSS:

## [***demo***](http://dabblet.com/gist/4590716)

The **HTML** is simply `<div class='diamond'></div>`

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.diamond {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20%;
    width: 0;
    transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866);
}
.diamond:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%; right:  -37.5%; bottom:  0; left:  -37.5%;
    transform: scaleY(1.155) skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-size: 6px;
    content: ''
}
```

Comment: How did you get all the numbers right? Trial and error, or did you calculate them?

Comment: Ok. Could you elaborate on the `1.155` please? What was the calculation?

Comment: `1/.866` and `.866` is `sqrt(3)/2` which is `sin(60deg)`, which is the acute angle of the parallelogram you get after applying `skewX(30deg)`.

Comment: The reason I apply a `scaleY` is that after skewing the element, the length of its top & bottom sides remains unchanged and so does the distance between them (which is equal to the top & bottom sides since we started with a square), but the length of the lateral sides increases and now the lateral sides are hypotenuses in right triangles that also have an angle of `60deg` and, opposite to that angle, a side that equals the side of the initial square. So I need to scale the hypotenuses down to that value, which is `.866` of one such hypotenuse.

Answer (score 4):

CSS striped diamond using the code you have given: http://jsfiddle.net/r3PNs/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="diamond"></div>
<div class="stripes" style=""></div>
```

CSS:

```
#diamond {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 80px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}
#diamond:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 80px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid red;
}

.stripes {
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  background-size: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using borders to create the diamond and a background to create the stripes.  These will not work together.  You can instead rotate the striped box to get the diamond:

```
.stripes {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background-size: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```